# Update property from interface

Tags: c#

I have an interface with a property:

```
public interface IMyInterface
    {

        string Test { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the class that implements it:

```
public MyClass : IMyInterface
{
        private string _test;
        public string Test
        {
            get { return _test; }
            set
            {
                _test = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Test");
            }
        }

    Public void MethodName()
    {
      //Logic that updates the value for Test
    }
}
```

So far all is well, when the method gets called, `Test` gets updated.

I also have a ViewModel that takes this implementation of `IMyInterface` in its constructor.

```
private IMyInterface _myInterface;

 public ViewModel(IMyInterface myinterface)
        {

            _myInterface = myinterface;

        }
```

Is it possible for me to have a property in my `ViewModel`  that gets updated each time the value of `Test` changes?

Comment: You could just add an event to your interface.  Are you trying to re-invent WPF dependency properties?

Comment: @HansPassant, would you mind showing how to add an event to my interface?
Been looking around but haveing a hard time finding an example that fits my need with the VM. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a new field - what you can do is just add another property to your ViewModel to re-expose your composed interface property:

```
public ViewModel
{
    // ...
    public string Test
    {
        get { return _myInterface.Test; }
        set {_myInterface.Test = value }
    }
}
```

**Edit, Re raising PropertyChanged events**

I would recommend that you require that `IMyInterface` extends `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public interface IMyInterface : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Which would then be implemented by your underlying concrete class like so:

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    private string _test;
    public string Test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set
        {
            _test = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Test");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // Null means no subscribers to the event
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!
I added your code to my VM and called that method that updates the property in MyClass. For some reason the property in the VM did not get hit. I put a breakpoint but it seems that the VM is not aware of the change? Could I be missing something?

Comment: The ViewModel will always be in synch with its `_myInterface` field, simply because it 'reaches through' to the composed `_myInterface`s property. If, in addition keeping the property 'in synch' you also require a notification event, you would also need to expose on your interface and propogate the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event, as per Hans' comment.