# Property wont bind to view

Tags: c#, wpf

Got good help here earlier regarding getting a property from another class using an eventhandler. 
[Update property from interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754628/update-property-from-interface/27754661?noredirect=1#comment43920662_27754661)

The result is a property that looks like this on my ViewModel and it does not behave in a familiar way.

```
 public string Test
    {
        get { return _myInterface.Test; }
        set {_myInterface.Test = value }
    }
```

This is a property that  I would like to bind to my view. Normally I would do it like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}"/>
```

It does not work on this specifik property. 
When hovering over value I can see that the `value` is there. But when i hover over the propertyname, nothing happens.

Edit:

```
 public double Test
    {
        get { return _myInterface.Test; }
        set
        {
            _myInterface.Test = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Test");
        }

    }
```

public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Complete code:

Interface:

```
 public interface IMyInterFace: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        string Test { get; set; }
    }
```

Class that implements it:

```
public class MyClass : MyInterface
    {

        private string _test;
        public string Test
        {
            get { return _test; }
            set
            {
                _test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Test");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }


        public void MyMetod()
        {
            //logic that updates Test
        }
```

ViewModel: (takes the IInterface in constructor.)

```
 public string Test
        {
            get
            {
                return _myInterface.Test;
            }
            set
            {
                _myInterface.Test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

The OnPropertyChanged in the VM does never get hit..

UPDATE:

This is now my view-model:

I got rid of MVVM-light and now do it like this:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public string Test
            {
                get { return _myInterface.Test; }
                set
                {
                    _myInterface.Test = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Test");
                }

            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }

}
```

But the event-handler never gets hit. The `Value` in the Test-property never gest assigned properly. Even though I can "see" the value when hovering over `value`.  Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: Looks ok. It won't update as you did not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but other than that, it looks fine. You will need to post more code.

Comment: Thank you, I made an edit where I (hopefully correctly) have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. Still no update to the view though..

Comment: Check the `DataContext` of your `Window` object (or whatever container you're using). [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) might be a good way of debugging your binding.

Comment: So... did you get binding errors in the output window of your visual studio?

Comment: Sorry, i do not know how to check my bindings in the output-window. Reading up on it now.

Comment: If I assign a value to Test in the ctor of the view-model, the binding works. This should let us eliminate binding-problems right?
To me the problem seems to be assigning the value to the property.

Comment: try to use the implementation code I uploaded on my answer..

Comment: thanks. Still it does not assign the value.

Answer (score 1):

You're **hiding** the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` in your viewmodel's base class with the `new` keyword.

```
public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Presumably, your viewmodel is inheriting from some other class that also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If that's the case, you don't need to reimplement the interface.

Update:

I took an existing project of mine and broke it in the same way as follows:

Given an existing Notifier base class:

```
public class NotifierBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

and an implementor:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : NotifierBase
{
    private bool someProperty;
    public bool SomeProperty 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.someProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.someProperty != value)
            {
                this.someProperty = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I changed the view model class as follows:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : NotifierBase
{
    private bool someProperty;
    public bool SomeProperty 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.someProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.someProperty != value)
            {
                this.someProperty = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This broke in exactly the same way you're describing. Only implement the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` **once**.

Comment: You are right. Im using MVVM-light which lets my VM inherit an RaisePropertyChanged. Even after deleting the "new"-keyword it does not get hit. But I think we might be on to somethibg with this...

Comment: Don't just delete the `new` keyword -- remove the event and the method from the class. If MVVM light (which I'm not familiar with) gives you a base class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, just use the implementation in the base class... or don't use MVVMLight's base class. Either/or. Just don't have two implementations of the event, because that's what's causing your problem.

Comment: Thank you! Please have a look at the update if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise it when setting your `Test` like

```
public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public string Test
        {
            get
            {
                return _myInterface.Test;
            }
            set
            {
                _myInterface.Test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set the "UpdateSourceTrigger" to "PropertyChanged"?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Test,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I would also check the DataContext.
just to be sure, try to explicit mention the DataSource

for example if you got a resource with a Key named: "MainViewModel"
then:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Test,Source={StaticResource MainViewModel},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

*Edit:
can you please try this implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged instead of what you have:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

*Edit#2:
on your last piece of code (ViewModel) looks like you forgot to pass the name of the property to the OnPropertyChanged() method.

```
public string Test
        {
            get
            {
                return _myInterface.Test;
            }
            set
            {
                _myInterface.Test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips, tried adding:
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.
Same result...

Comment: Still does not get hit. 
In myClass, if I put a breakpoint in the setter of Test. It stops, I can then "change page" in Visual studio and look att the ViewModel.cs-file. If hold the mouse over value, I can there see the correct value. But it does not get properly assigned to the property.